# delphi TRibbon rightToLeft AppliactionMenu cover the [X] Close Window Button

Tags: delphi, ribbon, delphi-xe7

- Creating a new Delphi Vcl Forms Application.
- Drop TRibbon
- Drop ActionManager
- Connect Between them.
- Right click the Ribbon1 to add Tabs and Groups.
- Right click the Ribbon1 to add Application Menu.
- In the Object Inspector choose the Ribbon1, and set BidiMode to bdRightToLeft.

Run.

The Form that is created is deffrent from design time, as the application menu covers the Close Appliaction button.

[image: Delphi Application Menu of TRibbon Right To Left]

What can be done to lower the Application Button?

Comment: Probably best to switch to the MS ribbon which offers at least some hope of RTL support. The image you show here has offer fundamental problems. Those ribbon tabs should be right aligned for a start.